# Need software to record from external system

Tags: software-recommendation

Want to record from external source such as audio cassette to the computer,what software is the best,is kazam any good.

Answer (score 4):

If you have used recording software in the past, such as Sony Sound Forge, Adobe Audition, or if you never used such recording software you may wish to give a chance to [Audacity.](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

[image]

With Audacity you may choose which sound signal you wish to record from: Line Input, Microphone or any available in your sound card. This will create the waveform when recording and when finished you will be able to adjust audio levels by mastering your audio with useful plugins included in the installation.

From the site:

> Audacity is a free, easy-to-use and multilingual audio editor and
>   recorder for Windows, Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and other operating systems.
>   You can use Audacity to:
>
> 1. Record live audio.
> 2. Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
> 3. Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
> 4. Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
> 5. Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
> 6. And more! [See the complete list of features.](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features)

***Audacity is included in the default software sources of Ubuntu and you can install it from Software Center.***

## Illustrations

First of all we need a common "Y" cable with 1/8" stereo miniplug and 2 RCA male connectors as this:

[image]

I am going to use a common TEAC cassette deck player with pitch like this:

[image]

(Note: The Audio Mixer is not needed and the snake is optional...)

In the back side of the cassete deck player, I am going to plug the both the RCA male connectors in the corresponding RCA female **OUTPUT** connectors as shown in the next picture:

[image]

Remember that "the corresponding RCA female OUTPUT connectors" may read something like "OUTPUT", "Line Out", "Out", etc.

After that, we need to plug the 1/8" stereo mini in the other edge of the cable, to the corresponding "Line Input" of the computer. I am using a Desktop computer so I am going to plug it in the Blue jack as shown in the next 2 pictures (hand thanks to **Jessi Yems**)

[image]
[image]

Audacity usually comes ready to record from "Line in". If you experience some problems when getting the audio signal from line in, try changing the default line input IN AUDACITY. After which you can check your sound settings in the Input Tab in order to see if the sound card is getting some sound signal as in the next example:

[image]

If you need further support don't hesitate to leave a comment. Thank you.

Good luck!

Comment: How do you line input and output,i can't find any option like that.

Comment: In the toolbar, there is a combo box that reads "ALSA" (see the picture that I placed in the answer), this combo allow you to select which sound engine is in use for recording/playback, beside it you'll find two "default" combos in which you can choose which line is going to be used for the input. The output is configurable via Preferences in which you can also define your default input.

Comment: Basically i'm tring to record from tape recorder to my computer using line out cable from headphone socket of the tape recorder to the headphone socket of the computer,how can sound come from tape recorder to my computers so i can record it using audacity.

Comment: It is ussually achieved by the proper type of cable. You need a Stereo "Y" cable from 1/8" miniplug to dual male connector RCA which will extract the audio from the proper "Line Out" output RCA female connector (in the backside of your tape recorder or the proper dual stereo 1/8" miniplug in order to extract the audio from the headphone in the tape deck's front panel. If the plug in the frontpanel is 1/4" stereo plug simply get a 1/8"-to-1/4" convertor and do the proper connections, then start recording in Audacity. If you need further details, a diagram or illustrations please let us know.

Comment: BTW: The connections should be from Line Out/Headphone Out in the Tape Deck TOWARDS the LINE-IN in your sound card. Have it in consideration in order to run the proper connections so that the audio will be directed to the right place and it can be registered by Audacity (or any other software). Good luck!

Comment: Yes provide diagram and illustrations will help.

Comment: Ok sorry for the delay. Illustrations are in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I already know about that setup. My cassette deck has only one headphone port.

Comment: It is about the cable indeed. For that case you simply need a different cable, with 1/8" stereo miniplug on each end. Like this one: http://i242.photobucket.com/albums/ff266/Bowhunter70/stereodoublemalecable.jpg The process is the same indeed. Good luck!

Comment: I tried that cable no sound is coming out from my computer.

Comment: I am understanding that you wish to record FROM tape TO computer. This way no sound will output from your computer while recording. If you wish to "monitor" your audio while recording I suggest you to use a sound mixer (like the one I have in this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lFXd2.jpg) so that you can hear what you are recording. You must consider that feedback may occur if you fail the connections. IF you are trying to do something else please explain. Thank you.

Comment: I have with 2 audio sockets white and red at the back side of my hifi but when i connect the cable to the hifi and then other side to my computer no sound is coming out. Headphone lineout to my computer works fine with no sound output,which is tape deck connection,which record sound. With hifi connection no sound records and no output.

Comment: HiFi audio is usually digital. If this is the case, then no audio signal is sent from these connectors but data so your computer won't receive anything unless you decode such data into normal audio signals. But if it is normal audio signal then you may be experiencing some kind of hardware problem in your tape deck. First make sure your input signal is correctly amplified in the sound settings in order to get enough signal register in the sound card. And make sure the tape deck is delivering audio signal to other sound device (amplifier, mixer, etc.)

Comment: Audio sockets on the hifi are bringing sound from video sockets to the hifi,it seems the audio sockets are not output but input that's why the sound is not coming through my computer speakers.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Audacity but if you need a bit of Control take a look at !
[Ardour](http://ardour.org/)

[image: Ardour Mixer]